# I am trying to merge two tables in excel, but one of the tables comes out as a single column. How can I get all columns to appear?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, power-query

I am trying to merge two tables:
[image]

After I click "OK", I get this:
[image]

Any idea what is happening here?

Comment: I know there is one more step you have to do. I think it's Transform>Expand.

Comment: Probably found how to do it now - in case you've not press the the icon on the right of the column header - two little arrows.  That will expand the table.

Comment: click on the top-right "filter/triangle" | ref : https://youtu.be/fAL1ySBqJKI?t=3626